# help with causative clauses

Tags: causatives

I'm having some trouble with breaking a causative clause into its parts of sentence. please help.
for instance:
*I have her do my homework.*

what i have figured out is:
I= subject
Have=verb (because when i change the tense have changes and not do)
her= indirect object?
do my homework= direct object/complement(a main imperative clause on its own) ?

also in instances where the object(if its an object at all) is a third person singular, such as:
i made the girl make me coffee. we do not add the present simple S to the verb( in this instance make), why is that? (is it because its a bare clause, and there used to be a to-infinitive there and now only the infinitive remains?).
are there more instances where the verb is just an infinitive without an S.

to sum it up:
1)how do i break a causative clause into its parts of sentence.
2)why is the second verb in a causative clause not affected by anything
3)are there more instances where a verb is not affected by tense or subject.
please help.
thank you all.

Comment: It's called a catenative construction. "Have" is here a catenative verb and "do my homework" is catenative complement of "have". The intervening noun "her" is direct object of "have". The catenative complement "do my homework" is not an imperative -- it's a non-finite clause (infinitival) , hence the use of Its plain (infinitival) verb form "do".

Comment: first of all thank you for your taking the time to answer me.
I have a problem with this catenative verbs.
in that : Wikipedia says they are verbs which are followed by other verbs, but aren't to-infinitives a type of phrase which might be a noun, an adverb, or an adjective.
same goes for  non-finite clauses they just seem like to-infinitive phrases to me.
appreciate the help.

Comment: The term 'catenative' comes from the Latin word for 'chain' and is used for clauses that have a chain of verbs, sometimes separated by a noun. In your example the two verbs are "have" and "do" which are separated by the noun "her".  Wiki has some information that may help you, here [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb)

Answer (score 1):

Your example uses a [bare infinitive](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/), which is an infinitive that is not marked by a **to**. The words **tell** and **bid** have the same meaning, but one requires a **to-** infinitive and the other requires a bare infinitive:

> I told him **to go**
>   I bade him **go**

Bare infinitives are pretty common, as they are also used after modals:

> I must **go**

To analyse your sentence, the verb **have** is followed by an object and a bare infinitive clause:

> I = subject 
>    have = main verb 
>    her = object of have, and implicit subject of the bare infinitive
>    do = bare infinitive
>    my homework = object of bare infinitive

Answer (score 0):

Behavior of  **make, have, let (allow)** in the following **functional** structure:

- to **make someone [him, her, them, us, me, you] do something** = to "force" them to do it.
- to **have someone do something**=to ask them to do it.
- to **let someone do something**=to allow them to do it, give permission
- to **have/get something done** (passive form) = to cause a thing to happen

[get and help work differently in active voice, they take "to", but are also causative]

The basic structures above have the nouns or pronouns after the main verb as **indirect objects.** Only the main verb changes. **It's not**: **I have** and **she does my homework**. The structure is: I  **have her do** my homework. Her is an indirect object.

1) I make the girl bake a cake.

There is no s in the third person because there is no separate clause with a separate very from make. To make someone do something is invariable. **It's  not**: I make + she bakes. It's: I **make her bake a cake.**

2)  I have her do my homework every week. [present tense]

I had her do my homework last week, too. That's right, the **do** is invariable here, as in the example above with make.

Answering the question: **The second verb is not affected because it is part of a functional structure and not a separate verb**. I have given the main ones above. The only verb that changes tense is the first one.

> **The main verb + the indirect object (pronoun or noun) + make, have, let + the direct object are a functional unit.**
>
> Also, **the only tenses that change in these structures is the tense of the first verb.**

[good summary of causatives that is simple to see and read](http://www.euenglish.hu/2016/01/causative/)